# Why can I not access my own website - unknown host?

Tags: web-browsing, dns, network

I have a website - www.birupakhyadash.com - which I am not able to access. The `traceroute` to the address returns the error: unknown host.

I have tried to clear the dns cache and disable the adblockplus browser extension, but for some reasons I am still unable to access the site.

How can I fix the "unknown host" error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How is your system getting its DNS resolutions?

Do you have DNS servers configured in your router config or in your NIC config? If you don't and it is not pushed to your router from your ISP maybe try setting them yourself.

Use Google's DNS;

- 8.8.8.8
- 8.8.4.4

Or OpenDNS;

- 208.67.222.222
- 208.67.220.220

If you have custom DNS servers set either in your router config or your computer's NIC config, maybe those are failing. Try removing them.

Are you able to access the site from any other computer or network other than your own?

Are you accessing the website from your home network, company or school network, some other private network? Your website might be blocked!

Have you made any changes to your website's DNS record recently, which might still be propagating?

Comment: Yes, my Dns Server (system pref -> network -> ethernet) already has two values. Should I change them with Google's? Is that what you are suggesting.

Comment: Yes, I am able to access my site from other computers, through proxy servers.

Comment: Here's my dns report, if that would be helpful.

http://www.dnssniffer.com/en/report/www.birupakhyadash.com

Comment: Changing the DNS to 8.8.8.8 did the job. Thanks! Weird why the previous DNS could not resolve the address now, when it was able to do so some days back.

Comment: I am able to access your website. Are your NIC's DNS setting auto-configed from your router or did you add them? Just for testing, try changing them to Google's or OpenDNS' IPs. Also what type of router are you using? Have you tried rebooting your router. It might help clear its cache.

Comment: Good to see that changing the DNS servers did the trick. The old servers might have had stale cache. If they were your ISP's DNS servers the cache might refresh only once every 24 hours. I have had the same issue after making changes to a website's DNS record.

Comment: I have bought this domain recently. Does that mean my ISP's DNS is old and perhaps there is no mapping in there? Even if the cache refreshes every 24 hours what difference does it make?

Comment: If there is no cached route their servers will lookup the route from other DNS severs. ISPs usually expire their DNS cache every 24, which means that next time a domain routing is requested from their DNS servers if the cache is stale (more than 24 hours old) they will lookup the route from other servers. If you made DNS changes to the domain record within the last 24 hours the changes might have not propagated through the Internet in time for your ISP to receive the correct records.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your DNS server has the zone "birupakhyadash.com". Best to create a www alias to the website's IP.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about this? Including how to create an alias?